Nest Js Exceptions handling
I am implementing authentication in Nest Js. According to Nest Js best practices, inside services should be business logic and inside controllers we can handle all exceptions (to throw or to catch them).
 Here is my AuthenticationService
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private readonly prismaService: PrismaService) {
  }
  async register(registerDto: RegisterDto) {
    const { email, password } = registerDto;
    const dbUser = await this.prismaService.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            email,
        },
    });

    if (dbUser) {
        return null
    }

    return this.prismaService.user.create({
        data: {
            email,
            password,
        },
    });
  }

My concern is related to this code
  if (dbUser) {
        return null
    }

I am checking if there is already a user with same email and return null in case if there exists such users.

I am not sure if this approach is correct or not, i am not sure if i handled correct in service, the scenario when user already exists. Because in controller i intend  to do next:

  @Post('register')
  register(@Body() registerDto: RegisterDto) {
    try {
      const result = this.authenticationService.register(registerDto);
        if (!result) {
            throw new HttpException('User already exists', 400);
        }
    } catch (error) {
      throw new HttpException(error.message, error.status);
    }

Question: Is this approach valid or it does not follow best practices?

In the answer below you said NestJS suggests throwing exceptions in the controller. So what is the question?

Where does Nest suggest throwing exceptions in the controller?

@SamuelGoldenbaum You are right, this is not mentioned directly, but they say: the main idea of a provider is that it can be injected as a dependency, which means that it is reusable and i agree. Let's imagine that you have a UserService that returns the user from DB, and inside that service you throw an exception, then you use that service in another service, let's say RegisterService, in this situation you can get unexpected errors inside RegisterService, this is why the services should be clean and to return only valid data. What do you think about this?

The best practices that my company uses are mostly using an early return and a clean controller class. This would mean bypassing the try catch in the controller class and pasting the HttpException message into the AuthenticationService once a DbUser is found.
Below you will find a possible elaboration of how we would carry out this.
AuthenticationService.ts
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private readonly prismaService: PrismaService) { }

  async register(registerDto: RegisterDto) {
    const { email, password } = registerDto;
    const dbUser = await this.prismaService.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            email,
        },
    });

    if (dbUser) {
        throw new HttpException('User already exists', 400);
    }

    return this.prismaService.user.create({
        data: {
            email,
            password,
        },
    });
  }

authentication.controller.ts
  @Post('register')
  register(@Body() registerDto: RegisterDto) {
    return this.authenticationService.register(registerDto);
  }


but this is against what NextJs team advices. Errors should be located in controllers and the services should be clean.

There is no reason to only throw exceptions in the controller; it is perfectly valid to throw them from your services, and Nest docs and courses do the same.
I typically handle input validation/auth validation as a guard and business logic errors within services.
You can also rather try use an equivalent exists query as there is no need to return the actual user as you don't do anything with it.
Also, think about returning a built-in HTTP Exception or using the HttpStatus enum HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
Given your scenario:
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private readonly prismaService: PrismaService) {
  }

  async register(registerDto: RegisterDto): Promise<User> {
    const { email, password } = registerDto;

    const userExists = this.prismaService.$exists.user({
       email
    });

    if (userExists) {
      throw new BadRequestException('user exists');
    }

    return this.prismaService.user.create({
        data: {
            email,
            password,
        },
    });
  }

